# UNIX shell: increment a variable with value of last returned exit code

Tags: bash, shell, variables, increment, return-code

Let's say I have a counter initialised by `counter=0`

Now I want to run a command and increment the value of counter by its returned exit code.

In a natural language I want to do `counter = $counter + $?`

I am trying stuff like `counter=$((counter+$((?))));` but with no success. What is the correct way to do it in a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash I suggest:

```
counter=$(($counter + $?))
```

This is also possible:

```
counter=$((counter + $?))
```

Or:

```
declare -i counter=0     # set integer attribute
<your command>
counter=counter+$?
```

Or:

```
declare -i counter=0
<your command>
counter=+$?
```

Comment: Might I suggest `((counter += $?))` as an additional variation.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value of `$?` to an intermediate variable then use arithmetic context to add:

Set `$?` to 22:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {exit 22}'
$ rtr=$?
$ counter=1
$ echo $((counter+rtr))
23
```

Answer (score 1):

In UNIX you can try:
counter=1;
counter=`expr $counter + 1`;
echo $counter;

Note:`expr $counter + 1` has space on both side of '+'